Looking to process 1d linear interpolation on a 3D gridded dataset
This is a follow-up question to an earlier question: Implementing 1D interpolation on a 3D Array in Numpy or Xarray
Tsoil is a 3D xarray dataset with the following dimensions:
<xarray.DataArray 'Tsoil' (lat: 1200, lon: 7200, depth: 4)>
dask.array<xarray-<this-array>, shape=(1200, 7200, 4), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1200, 7200, 4), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 30.03 30.08 30.13 30.18 ... 89.83 89.88 89.93 89.98
  * lon      (lon) float64 -180.0 -179.9 -179.9 -179.8 ... 179.9 179.9 180.0
  * depth    (depth) float64 3.5 17.5 64.0 194.5

This corresponds to soil temperatures at various depths along a lat/lon grid, such that the innermost dimension happens to be Tsoil. I want to interpolate Tsoil so that instead of temperature measurements at 4 depths, I have a much finer resolution of soil temperatures every 0.5cm between 0cm and 289cm. This requires me to perform a 1D interpolation on the innermost dimension of the XArray.
I have defined a function whose inputs are chunks from an xarray dataset:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import scipy
import dask.array as da

def interp1d_chunk(chunk, new_depths=new_depths, depths=depths):
    print(chunk)    
    nlat, nlon, _ = chunk.shape
    
    new_chunk = np.empty((nlat, nlon, len(new_depths)))
    
    for i in range(nlat):
        for j in range(nlon):
            f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(depths,chunk[i, j, :],bounds_error=False,fill_value="extrapolate")
            new_chunk[i, j, :] = f(new_depths)
            print(new_chunk)    
            return new_chunk

Say that Tsoil (for the purposes here) is a 3d array with size (4,4,4):
    test_array = np.asarray([[[ 9.984375  ,  9.315826  ,  6.753296  , -0.71829224],
    [ 9.812378  ,  9.15155   ,  6.6003723 , -0.7545166 ],
    [ 9.925293  ,  9.266205  ,  6.729767  , -0.67056274],
    [ 9.925293  ,  9.266205  ,  6.729767  , -0.67056274]],

   [[10.201508  ,  9.524597  ,  6.9415283 , -0.6557312 ],
    [ 9.812378  ,  9.15155   ,  6.6003723 , -0.7545166 ],
    [10.083374  ,  9.394531  ,  6.7566833 , -0.7775879 ],
    [ 9.925293  ,  9.266205  ,  6.729767  , -0.67056274]],

   [[10.201508  ,  9.524597  ,  6.9415283 , -0.6557312 ],
    [ 9.812378  ,  9.15155   ,  6.6003723 , -0.7545166 ],
    [10.083374  ,  9.394531  ,  6.7566833 , -0.7775879 ],
    [ 9.925293  ,  9.266205  ,  6.729767  , -0.67056274]],

   [[10.201508  ,  9.524597  ,  6.9415283 , -0.6557312 ],
    [10.109436  ,  9.4236145 ,  6.80542   , -0.7413635 ],
    [10.083374  ,  9.394531  ,  6.7566833 , -0.7775879 ],
    [10.083374  ,  9.394531  ,  6.7566833 , -0.7775879 ]]],dtype=np.float32)

    test_lats = [60.275, 60.325, 60.375, 60.425]
    test_lons = [140.75, 140.8, 140.85, 140.9]

    depths=np.asarray([3.5,17.5,64,194.5])
    new_depths = np.arange(0,289.1,0.5)

I'll create a dummy XArray called test_stemp:
    test_stemp = xr.DataArray(test_array,'lat':test_lats,'lon':test_lons,'depth'
                                   coords={'lat':lats,'lon':lons,'depth':depths}, 
                                   dims=['lat','lon','depth']).rename('Tsoil').chunk(chunks={lat_var:len(test_lats),lon_var:len(test_lons),'depth':4})

I then try to run it through interp1d_chunk, and interpolate along new_depths, but it seems like the function is being passed a chunk size of zero:
stemp_interp = da.map_blocks(interp1d_chunk, chunk=test_stemp, new_depths=new_depths, depths=depths, dtype='float',chunks=(len(test_lats),len(test_lons),len(new_depths)))

<xarray.DataArray (lat: 0, lon: 0, depth: 0)>
array([], shape=(0, 0, 0), dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 
  * lon      (lon) float64 
  * depth    (depth) float64

Does anyone have a suggestion of what could be wrong with my function or procedure here?

This is expected behavior.

Note that map_blocks will attempt to automatically determine the output array type by calling func on 0-d versions of the inputs. Please refer to the meta keyword argument below if you expect that the function will not succeed when operating on 0-d arrays.

https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.map_blocks.html
Since meta is not defined, it calls your function with a (0, 0, 0) array. You could define meta, or you could change the return value in this case so that it returns an array even if the length of the first two axes is zero.
def interp1d_chunk(chunk, new_depths, depths):
    print(chunk)
    nlat, nlon, _ = chunk.shape
    
    new_chunk = np.zeros((nlat, nlon, len(new_depths)))
    
    for i in range(nlat):
        for j in range(nlon):
            f = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(depths,chunk[i, j, :],bounds_error=False,fill_value="extrapolate")
            new_chunk[i, j, :] = f(new_depths)
            print(new_chunk)    
    return new_chunk

Note that I un-indented return new_chunk by two indents. I think this is also a good change to make for the sake of correctness - it doesn't make sense to return new_chunk after only interpolating one set of depth values.
I also changed np.empty() to np.zeros(). While np.empty() can be faster, it can also cause you to use uninitialized memory. It's usually not worth the trouble of getting non-deterministic results.
Finally, note that this computation is lazy. Until you call stemp_interp.compute(), it will not actually do the interpolation.

Thank you - it seems that the placement of the return was causing my data to become corrupted! Looks like it is now giving me what I am looking for!
